# Why is my simulation not loading when V2 has no current?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator

I'm trying to make a two power source circuit that regulates 9V6 to 5V. The supply is not gonna be connected all time, but I want to make sure that when it is connected, just uses the voltage supply, not the battery one (I don't want to discharge it). When I simulate the circuit, while VSupply has no voltage, it simulates fine, but when VSupply = 9V6, it gets stuck the very first moment. Any ideas how to solve it? I just edited the circuit because i misconnected one power supply to the gate.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things wrong with the simulation, the first is the gate is floating on AD6407, this will make it difficult for the solver to determine what the sim is because of the floating gate. Add in parasitics for all caps and inductors. You also may want to provide a small amount of series resistance, you also need to do this in a way you are not tying two voltage sources together, that will generate infinite amounts of current and wreck havoc on the solver. (have you ever tried to solve a circuit equation with infinities in it? It doesn't make a lot of physical sense).

Comment: I need 2 A to flow into ADP2302, which resistor should I put?

Comment: I just fixed the gate  (I missclicked), but it doesnt work still.

Comment: Put in parasitics

Comment: Thanks, now it works. But I'm worried about a 9A spike in the first moment of the simulation, any idea?